# Bootstrap- img tag doesn't fit in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two div, each having an image and paragraph inside. when I gave class `col-md-5` to the divs the `img` tag doesn't cover all the divs space. How can I fix that? Codes and `JsFiddle` are following.

HTML:

```
<div id="recent-posts" class="center-block">
            <div class="posts col-md-5">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success">title</button>
                <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
            </div>
            <div class="posts col-md-5">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" >title</button>
                <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Css:

```
#recent-posts{
    width: 70%;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.posts{
    width: 40%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.posts img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.posts .btn-success{
    background-color: #01a89e;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 227px;
    left: 24%;
    color: #101010;
    cursor: auto;
}
.posts p{
    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(46, 183, 175, .7);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    transition: .8s ease;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.overlay div:first-child{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.posts-div:hover .overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 70%;
}
.posts-div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmsvjps8/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because each Bootstrap column has `padding-left:15px` `padding-right:15px` so the content stays inside the column but does not cover the padding.

So you have a few solutions for this.

1. add a div that will contain all the content inside the column and give borders to that div

See below or > [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmsvjps8/4/)

```css
#recent-posts {
  width: 70%;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.posts {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.post-container {
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
}

.posts img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.posts .btn-success {
  background-color: #01a89e;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 227px;
  left: 24%;
  color: #101010;
  cursor: auto;
}

.posts p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(46, 183, 175, .7);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .8s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.overlay div:first-child {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.posts-div:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 70%;
}

.posts-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="recent-posts" class="center-block">
  <div class="posts col-md-5">
    <div class="post-container">


      <div class="posts-div">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success">title</button>
      <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="posts col-md-5">
    <div class="post-container">
      <div class="posts-div">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success">title</button>
      <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. remove the `paddings` from the `col-md-5`

see snippet below or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmsvjps8/5/)

```css
#recent-posts{
    width: 70%;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.posts{
    width: 40%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.posts.col-md-5 {
 padding-left:0;
 padding-right:0;
}
.posts img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.posts .btn-success{
    background-color: #01a89e;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 227px;
    left: 24%;
    color: #101010;
    cursor: auto;
}
.posts p{
    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(46, 183, 175, .7);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    transition: .8s ease;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.overlay div:first-child{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.posts-div:hover .overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 70%;
}
.posts-div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent-posts" class="center-block">
            <div class="posts col-md-5">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">
                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success">title</button>
                <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
            </div>
            <div class="posts col-md-5">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" >title</button>
                <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

3. a non-orthodox  solution would be to increase the width of the image with 30px ( equal to right left padding of the column )  and then move it to the left by 15px to center it

See snippet below or > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmsvjps8/6/)

```css
#recent-posts{
    width: 70%;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.posts{
    width: 40%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.posts img{
    width: calc(100% + 30px);
    height: 100%;
  margin-left:-15px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.posts .btn-success{
    background-color: #01a89e;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 227px;
    left: 24%;
    color: #101010;
    cursor: auto;
}
.posts p{
    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(46, 183, 175, .7);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    transition: .8s ease;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.overlay div:first-child{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.posts-div:hover .overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 70%;
}
.posts-div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent-posts" class="center-block">
            <div class="posts col-md-5">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">
                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success">title</button>
                <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
            </div>
            <div class="posts col-md-5">
                <div class="posts-div">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" >title</button>
                <p class="text-center">dljfsdljfdsl;jfdsljfdljf</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: your solutions except 2 are actually pretty good but way to complex for him/her i think, all (s)he needs is a padding of 0 on the posts class, and removing the paddings from the col-md-5 might mess up his/her entire website.

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand you realize that removing the padding from `.posts` is removing the padding from `col-md-5` ? `<div class="posts col-md-5">` .

Comment: removing the padding from posts removes the padding from only the div that has posts, so the original col-md-5 is still untouched which includes not messing up the entire website

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand if you would've taken a look at my code i wrote `.posts.col-md-5 {` so it will remove the padding only from those specific columns that also have class `posts`

Comment: but why make it more difficult than needed

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand giving more than one solution to a problem is making it more difficult ? also i wrote `.posts.col-md-5 {`  to be more specific as boostrap css might overwrite the custom style css , so to be sure the style `padding:0` is applied, i wrote a more specific selector. that's not making it more difficult

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand I understand your solution, Thanks.

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks, It works but I don't understand How adding another `div` fix `padding` issue !?

Comment: the padding is not 'fixed' it's still there and it's default bootstrap css style . it's just `visual` because you add the borders to the `post-container` not to the `posts` . so the container will be smaller than the `posts` but the image will cover the space between the borders ( padding is still there ) . BUT using this container you don't have to give custom `width:40%` to `col-md-5` and  thus changing default bootstrap css

Answer (score -1):

if you want to solve this i have found an easy fix using your code,

append the class:

```
 class="img-responsive"
```

to your images and on the css make some changes as following:

```
.posts {
    width: 40%;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #888888;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
}
```

the change that was made was the : `Padding:0;`

see the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ah35gs3/) as an example